# How can i group the elements by key and append the values for that particular key using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a requirement to group the elements by key and append the values for that particular key using JavaScript . Below is the actual and expected data. Can anyone please help me to fix it ?

**Actual**

```
[
    {
        "num": 152332,
        "subReport": "HS_ONE"
    },
    {
        "num": 152332,
        "subReport": "HS_TWO"
    },
    {
        "num": 152331,
        "subReport": "HS_THREE"
    },
    {
        "num": 152331,
        "subReport": "HS_FOUR"
    }
]
```

**Expected**

```
[
    {
        "num": 152332,
        "subReport": "HS_ONE,HS_TWO"
    },    
    {
        "num": 152331,
        "subReport": "HS_THREE,HS_FOUR"
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? I believe [#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) could help here.

Comment: Give some code about what you have done so far.  I thin a nice approach of this issue is to go through the array and generate a new array, for each new num you create an object if it already exists you append the subreport and you can use some method as reduce or do the loop

Comment: @Nico : I have just generated the actual data which you can see above. I am struggling to get that expected data. Let me try the approach you have suggested.

Comment: @sp00m Thank you. I will check using reduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` with `find`:

```js
const arr = [
  { num: 152332, subReport: 'HS_BIT' },
  { num: 152332, subReport: 'HS_LOG' },
  { num: 152331, subReport: 'HS_LOG' },
  { num: 152331, subReport: 'HS_GENERAL' }
]

const out = arr.reduce((a, o) => {
  const item = a.find(i => i.num === o.num)
  item ? (item.subReport = `${item.subReport},${o.subReport}`) : a.push(o)
  return a
}, [])

console.log(out)
```

However, this will result in a time complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>). Using a map will help reduce this to O(n):

```js
const arr = [
  { num: 152332, subReport: 'HS_BIT' },
  { num: 152332, subReport: 'HS_LOG' },
  { num: 152331, subReport: 'HS_LOG' },
  { num: 152331, subReport: 'HS_GENERAL' }
]
const map = new Map([])
const out = arr.reduce((a, o, i) => {
  const num = map.get(o.num)
  num + 1 ? a[num].subReport = `${a[num].subReport},${o.subReport}` : map.set(o.num, a.push(o) - 1) 
  return a
}, [])

console.log(out)
```

Comment: @Nithin No problem. If you ever need more help, feel free to ask 

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Map` and `reduce`

```js
let data = [{"num": 152332,"subReport": "HS_BIT"},{"num": 152332,"subReport": "HS_LOG"},{"num": 152331,"subReport": "HS_LOG"},{"num": 152331,"subReport": "HS_GENERAL"}]

let final = data.reduce((op,{num,subReport})=>{
  op.set(num, op.get(num) && (op.get(num) + ',' + subReport) ||  subReport)
  return op
},new Map())

let output = [...final].map(([num,subReport])=>({num,subReport}))

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const data = [{"num": 152332,"subReport": "HS_ONE"},{"num": 152332,"subReport": "HS_TWO"},{"num": 152331,"subReport": "HS_THREE"},{"num": 152331,"subReport": "HS_FOUR"}];
const obj = data.reduce((a, {num, subReport}) => (a[num] = a[num] ? [...a[num], subReport] : [subReport], a), {});
const result = Object.keys(obj).map(k => ({ num: k, subReport: obj[k].join(', ') }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop the array and create a custom Object data structure with unique key on `num`. Then, get the values of the object to make the final array as expected:

```js
var arr = [{
    "num": 152332,
    "subReport": "HS_BIT"
  },
  {
    "num": 152332,
    "subReport": "HS_LOG"
  },
  {
    "num": 152331,
    "subReport": "HS_LOG"
  },
  {
    "num": 152331,
    "subReport": "HS_GENERAL"
  }
];
let resObj = {};
arr.forEach((obj) => {
  if (resObj[obj.num]) {
    resObj[obj.num].subReport += ', ' + obj.subReport
  } else {
    resObj[obj.num] = obj;
  }
});
var resArray = Object.values(resObj);
console.log(resArray);
```

> This approach is also better for array with large size as the complexity is only `O(n)` which is more when we use `reduce()`.

Comment: Im not sure why you don't use reduce here? You're literally using an object on the outside, that could be used inside reduce, without sacrificing performance?

Comment: Using `reduce` we need to use `find` which will make `O(n2)` complexity, And this approach is `O(n)`

Comment: I mean, you don't. You are accessing an object by keyname. You could do this with reduce, too.